# I get an error for a function I don't even call

Tags: solidity, contract-development, ethers.js

I got an error which I don't understand, and that I don't remember defining anywhere in the code, can someone explain what the issue is? Thanks a lot.

```
 properties_1.defineReadOnly(this, "fragments", abi.map(function (fragment) {
                                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

This is my code:

```
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");
const {abi} = require('./build/abi/mycontract.json');
require('dotenv').config();
const { ALCHEMY_API_KEY, ACCOUNT2_PRIVATE_KEY, ACCOUNT2_PUBLIC_KEY,CONTRACT_ADDRESS} = process.env;


const provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider('rinkeby', {
    alchemykey: ALCHEMY_API_KEY
});
const wallet = new ethers.Wallet.createRandom();
const walletWithProvider = wallet.connect(provider);

const mycontract = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS,abi,walletWithProvider);

async function stakeliquidity(){
     await contractW.stakeCombinedLiquidity()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('staked succesfully');
    }).catch(() => console.log('transaction error'));
 console.log('function called.');
}
stakeliquidity();
//Unstake
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR; The `abi` declared in your Line 2 (`const {abi} = ..`) could be undefined. You can verify it bby console logging.

You get the `Cannot read property '*' of undefined` error when somewhere in your code if you're using a library, you're passing an undefined value by mistake. Also, this says `property 'map'`, which means that the library function expects the value as an Array. Luckily, you also have a code snippet that triggered this error and it contains `abi.map`, and the variable name suggests it's `abi`, though this is from ethers.js codebase not yours.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It turned out that the abi was incorrect so I generated a new one and that worked. Thanks a lot.